# how to compare multiple words in a sentence in excel

Tags: excel

the formula is:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MICROSOFT OFFICE", C2)), ["TRUE"], [IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ms OFFICE", C2)), ["TRUE"], [IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ms-OFFICE", C2)), ["TRUE"], ["FALSE"])])])

and error is in the picture
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLCyi.jpg)

Comment: search for "office"and remove any "libre office" ...

Answer (score 2):

Remove all square brackets:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MICROSOFT OFFICE", C2)), "TRUE", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ms OFFICE", C2)), "TRUE", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ms-OFFICE", C2)), "TRUE", "FALSE")))
```